# EmailAttribute and Required Validation Fails

Tags: c#, .net, razor, blazor, .net-5

I have a model with an `Email` property for a form in a Blazor server app:

```
class Inputs
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I also have this helper class (for context):

```cs
public class FormModel<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private readonly EditContext EditContext;

    public FormModel()
    {
        Model = new T();
        EditContext = new EditContext(Model);
    }

    public T Model
    {
        get;
        init;
    }

    public EditContext Validation => EditContext;
}
```

**When I run validation against the value `"admin"`, I get back `true` instead of `false`**:

```cs
private readonly FormModel<Inputs> Form = new(); 

private void Submit() {
    // Debugger: Form.Model.Email = "admin"
    bool isValid = Form.Validation.Validate(); // true - not what I expect for "admin"
    if (!isValid) {
        return;
    }
    // ... code that should not be currently hit, but is ...
}
```

Debugger when I run this:
[image: Debugger 2]

The same thing happens when `Email` is not provided at all (though I'm not sure if `[Required]` considers an empty string a non-answer?):
[image: Debugger 1]

I've used `[EmailAddress]` in other places in the app and validation works as expected.
[image: Working as I would expect]

What might cause validation to fail here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add a `DataAnnotationsValidator` to my `<EditForm>` in the razor markup:

```html
<EditForm EditContext="@Form.Validation" OnValidSubmit="Submit">

    <DataAnnotationsValidator /> @* <-- was missing this *@

    <InputText @bind-Value="@Form.Model.Email"
                class="standard-input"
                type="email"
                placeholder="Email" />
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Form.Model.Email)" />
    ...
</EditForm>
```

This is necessary because the `DataAnnotationsValidator`:

> Adds Data Annotations validation support to an EditContext.